# Finding an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g(z) = f(z)$ for $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone help me with the following problem, I've been stuck on it for hours now and have no idea of how to approach it. Thanks!

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<1$ and $|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq 1$ for all $n =0,1,2,...$. Show that there is an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ for $|z|<1$.

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of $\sum ( f^{(n) }(0) /n!)z^n$?

Comment: They don't tell me, that is the whole statement of the problem.

Comment: There is a formula for the radius of convergence!

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$ g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!} z^j
$$
Since $f$ is analytic, $g$ agrees with $f$ in the open unit disk. To show that $g$ is entire, observe that
$$ \lim_{j \to \infty} \sqrt[j]{\left|\frac{f^{(j)}(0)}{j!}\right|} \leq \lim_{j \to \infty} \sqrt[j]{\frac{1}{j!}} = 0
$$
By Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, $g$ converges everywhere.